# C pointer confusion - pointer to char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

This should be simple, but pointers to char arrays still leave me scratching my head sometimes.  gcc complains that "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer" in lines 4 and 5, and "invalid type argument of 'unary *'" on lines 8 and 11.  Can someone explain what is going wrong here?  I changed lines 4 and 5 to dereference the pointer first using brackets, but still can't get what I want.

This should be a pretty simple function:

```
1  void makesafestr ( const char *unsafe,  const char *safe )
2  {
3    int offset=0;
4    for (; (*safe)[offset] != "\0" ; offset++) {
5      switch ((*unsafe)[offset]) {
6        case "\n":
7        case "\r":
8          *safe[offset] = "~";
9          break;
10       default:
11         *safe[offset] = *unsafe[offset];
12     }
13     offset++;
14   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `safe` is a pointer to a char (not a pointer to an array). So when you say `*safe` that's a plain `char`. **Instead of `(*safe)[offset]` try `safe[offset]`**. Same goes for `*safe[offset]`, same goes for `unsafe`.

A second problem is the way you are comparing characters. "\0" is a *string literal*. In your code you want a *character literal*. In short, the `for` should be:

```
for (; safe[offset] != '\0' ; offset++)
```

But you could rewrite it and make it simpler, since `\0` is `0`:

```
for (offset=0; safe[offset]; offset++)
```

Comment: And this is why you don't need the '*'.
A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted
designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator []
is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that
apply to the binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2] designates the E2-th
element of E1 (counting from zero).

Comment: Wow that's complicated.  Does this mean that the pointer is ALWAYS dereferenced first, then the subscript added?  I was concerned that the compiler might assume it is an array of pointers, and use the address of 'safe' plus [offset], then dereference that address.

Comment: No.  `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`; the *result* of `a + i` is dereferenced (IOW, the offset is added before the dereference).  Had you declared `safe` as `char (*safe)[]` (a pointer to an array of `char`), *then* you would need to dereference the pointer before applying the subscript (and the parens around `*safe` would be mandatory -- subscripting has a higher precedence than dereference, so `*safe[i]` would be parsed as `*(safe[i])`, not `(*safe)[i]`, which would cause problems).

Answer (score 3):

The character constants need single quotes instead of double quotes:  `'\0', '\n', '\r', and '~'`

Also, the assignment to the `safe` probably will not be allowed since it is marked as `const` (after fixing the indirection issues already mentioned in other answers).

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `unsafe` and `safe` point to the first item of the character array.

`safe[4]` will be the fifth item (counting from zero) in the array i.e. the fifth character

So the code should be

```
void makesafestr ( const char *unsafe,  char *safe )  /* Do not need const for safe, as you are
                                                         constructing it */
{  
  int offset=0;  
  for (; unsafe[offset] != 0 ; offset++) /* Do not need the " - see below. Also would have
                                            thought you need to scan unsafe */
  {  
      switch (unsafe[offset]) {  
        case '\n':  /* Single quotes required as we are dealing with characters and not strings */
        case '\r':  
          safe[offset] = '~';  
          break;  
       default:  
          safe[offset] = unsafe[offset];  
     }  
     offset++; 
   }
   safe[offset] = 0; /* In C and C++ strings end with the null character */  
}
```

Note, a string (`"a string"`) in C and C++ is an array of characters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need asterisks in front of `safe` and `unsafe`. They're already pointers.
Also, you must use single quotes instead of double quotes. Single quotes are for chars, double quotes are for stings.